# Book: "Getting Started with Magento Extension Development", sql migration script not executed

Tags: magento

I have followed the same steps as mentioned in the Book, the key steps are:

1. create the resources setup configuration at `<Module Directory>/etc/config.xml` as follow:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <global>
           <modules>
               <Foggyline_HappyHour>
                   <version>1.0.0.0</version>
               </Foggyline_HappyHour>
           </modules>

           <!-- Some Other Configuration (Doesn't matter) -->

           <resources>
               <foggyline_happyhour_setup>
                   <setup>
                       <model>Foggyline_HappyHour</model>
                   </setup>
               </foggyline_happyhour_setup>
           </resources>

           <!-- Some Other Configuration (Doesn't matter) -->

       </global>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create a the migration script at `<Module Directory>/sql/foggyline_happyhour_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php` with the following script:

   ```
   <?php
   // Just checking if the script is executed
   echo 'Thank you for your help :)';
   ```
3. Load any pages and check if the page print the message.

Nope, it didn't print anything. The script didn't run at all.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:( Apparently there was a *typo* in the books ):

According to the [official docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#create_configuration_xml), the setup definition should be `<module>` instead of `<model>`. Thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>

        <!-- Some Other Configuration (Doesn't matter) -->

        <resources>
            <foggyline_happyhour_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
                </setup>
            </foggyline_happyhour_setup>
        </resources>

        <!-- Some Other Configuration (Doesn't matter) -->

    </global>
</config>
```

Now I can see the script executed. :)

Comment: have you succeeded what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, It is. This was another typo on the book. I can only mark as answer after 2 days